# BIRT - choose more then one option for a parameter

Tags: parameters, report, birt

I have a parameter named "Month" an I can choose one month for example: 03.2016.

But I will choose in Month for example more than one: 03.2016 and 05.2014

Can I realize it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use e.g. multi-select list. See [sample report](http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php?/files/file/593-default-value-all-with-multi-select-parsmeter/)